# Multi Dimensional Array Challenge

Tags: php, arrays, html

I have been reading endless posts today on php arrays, and multidimensional arrays ... I'm a tad confused :)

I have a mySql table that has rows that consist of the following columns:
name, email, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, choice6, choice7, choice8, choice9, choice10

I'm populating an array as follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$allResults[$index] = $row;
$index++;
}
```

I know I can access the data by $allResults[0][name]; that all is fine.

However here is what I'm trying to do.

One of the rows will include a piece of data: IPO3_1 (it would be in one of the choice columns)

I need to cycle through all of the rows in the array, find this data and then pull out the name column. Here is very rough code of my ultimate goal (although incomplete as I cannot get my head around this)

```
<TR>
<?php
if (in_array("IPO3_1", $allResults[0])||in_array("IPO3_1", $allResults[1])) {
?>
<TD WIDTH="30" ALIGN="CENTER"><input type="checkbox" name="sp1" value="IPO3_1" DISABLED></TD>
<?php
} else {
?>
<TD WIDTH="30" ALIGN="CENTER"><input type="checkbox" name="sp1" value="IPO3_1" ></TD>
<?php
}
?>
<TD WIDTH="210" ALIGN="LEFT">&nbsp;&nbsp;IPO3 - 1st</TD>
<TD WIDTH="40" ALIGN="CENTER">$120</TD>
<TD WIDTH="270" ALIGN="CENTER"><?php echo $allResults[0][name]; ?></TD>     
</TR>
```

Basically when I find the value "IPO3_1" in any row, I need to disable a checkbox , and also add the name into the table

There could be as many as 34 rows in my mySql table maximum. THere are 34 values similiar to "IPO3_1" but are all unique text strings.

Any thoughts to get me pointed in the right direction ?

Comment: Are those values like "IPO3_1" are in an array?

Comment: yes, in the $allResults array

Comment: No, those you check to present

Comment: Or  just one such value?

Comment: sorry, not necessarily. When someone purchases an item (one of the 34 available), those are then written into the database. So they might exist already if someone purchased, and if not .. they are absent

Comment: Is IPO3_1 a Value stored in some column or a field-name (name of an actual Column in the DB Table)?

Comment: I have a mySql table that has rows that consist of the following columns: name, email, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, choice6, choice7, choice8, choice9, choice10 ... "IPO3_1" would be in one of the columns named choice[x]

Comment: @Vacek have you seen my second link - https://eval.in/585648 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've written as undestood the task. But I'm not shure in my undestanding :)

```
// $row will be false if string will be not found anywhere
// else it will be index of row, in wwhich first occurence found
$row = false;

foreach($allResults as $key=>$value) {
    // remove non-'choice' fields
    unset($value['name']);
    unset($value['email']);
    // Lookup the string in other field 
    if(in_array('IPO3_1', $value, true))
        //  if found break the loop 
        { $row = $key;  break; }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i really don't understand what i can add there

Comment: Explain you code. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks splash58, but this doesnt help me along at all .. I'm as confused as when I asked the original question :) Maybe it just needs further explanation on how I implement it in the above.

Comment: let's try to understand together. The values that you are looking for,  are they known before, or they are unique values from allResults ?

Comment: Are thay in array?

Comment: no, but I can easily create an array with all the values.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Thanks. Just a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114156/discussion-between-vacek-and-splash58).

Comment: Ok. Really you want for every entry in that new array know index in allResults  array with that value present, or false when it absent. am I right?

Comment: Anyone else have any suggestions ?